# Table row with image and button below programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to do table with images and seekbar below every image.

In my layout.xml:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

</TableLayout>
```

Im my Main.java I do loop:

```
// outer for loop
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // inner for loop
    for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {

        // Picture
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);                
        image.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        image.setId(1);             

        row.addView(image);

        // Seekbar
        SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
        seekBar.setId(2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, image.getId());

        Log.d("BMT", Integer.toString(image.getId()));

        row.addView(seekBar, p);

    }

    table.addView(row);

}
```

The result of this is just table with pictures and no seek bars! I tryed a lot of combination, read posts in stackoverflow, but I think I miss something. Please, help me understand what I do wrong. I thought maybe Row should be RelativeLayout too, but it didn't work.

Comment: Any `View` directly contained in a `TableRow` needs to use `TableRow.LayoutParams`. Also, the way you're adding rows won't work. Couple options: 1) Put an `ImageView` and a `SeekBar` in a `Layout` of their own, then add that `Layout` to the `TableRow`. 2) Alternate between adding a row of `ImageView`s, then a row of `SeekBar`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your  problem.**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     // inner for loop
     for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
         // Picture
         ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
         image.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         image.setId(1);

         RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
         relativeLayout.addView(image);

         // Seekbar
         SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
         seekBar.setId(2);

         p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, image.getId());
         Log.d("BMT", Integer.toString(image.getId()));

         relativeLayout.addView(seekBar);
         row.addView(relativeLayout);

     }
}
```

Comment: I did that and app is not starting now:'07-16 20:16:37.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 20:16:37.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3455): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
07-16 20:16:37.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3455):  at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:587)'
'